# Can't assign String to AnyObject?

Tags: swift

Ok, this is a weird one. I'm looping through an array of what apparently is a `Dictionary<String, AnyObject?!>` (notice the `?!`, it's not a typo). I'm trying to assign a `String` to one of its keys, but it's not working and I get the weird error below.

Has anyone seen anything like this?

[image: Error]

**Edit**:

Some extra info: even the debugger says it's an `AnyObject?!`:

[image]

Comment: error shows all you want field is of AnyObject type .it is not possible to assign string to it.

Comment: Why not? You can do var something : AnyObject = "Some String"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot apply the `Dictionary` syntax on an `Array`.

Try this:

```
if var dict = fields as? [String: String]{
    dict["test"] = "test"
}
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to change the value of a property of a nested JSON object. I get back a dictionary with an array of dictionaries, if that makes sense.